# Bytestream implementation - is offset correctly implemented?

Tags: c++, c

I encountered some interesting code about byte streams.
For example, this is init method:

```
int aim_bstream_init(aim_bstream_t *bs, fu8_t *data, int len)
{

    if (!bs)
        return -1;

    bs->data = data;
    bs->len = len;
    bs->offset = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

But I am a bit confused how offset is implemented. Maybe I get offset notion wrongly,
and help appreciated. Like here:

```
int aim_bstream_setpos(aim_bstream_t *bs, int off)
{

    if (off > bs->len)
        return -1;

    bs->offset = off;

    return off;
}
```

The `>` in the if is confusing me. Say the length of the byte stream is 3.
And we say move to position `3` - this is not possible right? Because
we only have elements `0,1,2` if length is 3.

In the code, `if(off > bs->len)` - would check 3>3 - it would be false
and function would continue to set `bs->offset = off;` -
which I think is wrong  because if len=3, you can't have offset
3 right?

Comment: Maybe offset one past-the-end is allowed, to allow for loop over offset until your out of the bitstream?

Comment: @SørenDebois: maybe but usually it is not necessary right? If I write my own bytestream like this, I would like to disallow to move to the 'last' element. Because if array size is 3 - I only want to have 0,1,2  indexed elements. Actually in this case element with index 3 would not even exist, right?

Comment: @SørenDebois: And if I want to check if there is place in the bytestream to write 4 byte value, I have to make sure `length-offset>=4` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the `offset` is pointing to the end of the `bstream`.

This is like what `std::vector::end()` does.

Comment: ok but If I write my own bytestream like this, I would like to disallow to move to the 'last' element. Because if array size is 3 - I only want to have 0,1,2 indexed elements. Actually in that case element with index 3 would not even exist, right?

Comment: And if I want to check if there is place in the bytestream to write 4 byte value, I have to make sure `length-offset>=4` right?

Comment: Note `offset` does NOT mean `index`. That's why you should not write code like data[offset]. The idea is to hide the details of implementation, but provide the interface/iterator for others to use.

Comment: It does not mean index, but it is functioning like index right? e.g., a[2] is similar to data+2(offset), isn't it? Yes I will provide interface for that. But getElementWithIndex(2) would be similar like `data+2` (third element, just like in array)

Comment: Yes, but the point here is the `offset` in your case *really* means the offset, the valid range is [start, end). I think it's clear enough.

Comment: You can check std::vector::end() for the idea how it works. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/

Comment: I think I understand how this offset works right? I'll check the vector::end too